# How to rotate a picture in Scientific Word

Tags: rotating, scientific-workplace

I would be thankful if someone can help me to know how to import and rotate a picture in Scientific Word v 5.5. I wanna use TeX codes to import pictures but I face an error.

Comment: The typical command for import an image in LaTeX is `\includegraphics{img}` that is defined in the `graphicx` package. The format supported are: PDF, EPS, JPEG and PNG.

Comment: @vipa Thanks for your comment. I know this command for LaTeX but I want to import and rotate a picture in scientific word.

Comment: `\includegraphics[angle=90]{img}`